# How does --worker_threads=4 in osquery works?

Tags: osquery

Wanted to know if someone can help with working of --worker_threads=4 in osquery.
checked osquery documentation [osquery doc](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/1.8.2/installation/cli-flags/) but it contains only one line of explanation which is not helping. Just wanted to know behavior of worker_threads.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The flag `--worker_threads` has no effect. It was removed in a [PR](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/pull/1924) back in 2016.

The docs you link to are from `1.8.2` which is no where near the current version